# image as component issue

Tags: java, image, components

I am trying to do my final project for my java class.  I am attempting to take a .png picture and use it as a component that I can add to my JFrame.  However, when I try to do this it throws an exception and does what is in the catch statement.  I do not understand why it would do this.  I have the .png file in the same folder as my .java files.

```
package InventoryApp;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author Curtis
 */
public class FinalProject extends DFrame
{
//main method
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    start();
}

//building splash screen

public static void start()
{   DFrame splashFrame = new DFrame();
    try
    {
    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("logo.png"));
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
    splashFrame.add(picLabel);
    }
    catch(IOException g)
    {
        JLabel error = new JLabel("Picture Could Not Be Found");
        splashFrame.add(error);
    }


    JButton create = new JButton("Click to Create Item List");
    JButton view = new JButton("Click to View Item List");
    splashFrame.add(create);
    splashFrame.add(view);


}

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can figure that out?  I assumed it was throwing the exception when it was attempting to grab the file.

Comment: in the exception block, you need to print the exception.  Basically you can call `g.dumpStackTrace()` for a quick and dirty dump

Comment: @MadProgrammer ITYM `printStackTrace()`  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah thats it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `File` object with no path specified, it assumes the directory the program was launched from, *not* the directory the current class file is in. You probably want to instead use `FinalProject.class.getResource()`:

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(FinalProject.class.getResource("logo.png"));
```

Comment: Can you assist me with this code.  I am getting an error on it         BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(FinalProject.class.getResource("logo.png")));

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you could just dispense with `File` entirely and use the version of `ImageIO.read()` that takes a URL.